# Error: Grant type is not set while trying to generate the Token

Tags: python

I am working on a python script that generates the access token.
I am working on API calls for the first time.
I am getting the below error:
jsonResponse: {
'error_description': 'Grant type is not set', 'error': 'invalid_request'
}
I tried all the different grant_types but getting the same error.
Could someone help me?

```
import requests

import json

myToken = 'https://......../internal/access_token'

headers =      
   {

                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(myToken),
                   "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                   "Grant_Type":"client_credentials",
                    "scope": 'api-customer',
                    "client_id": '<Clientid>',
                    "client_secret": '<secret>'
  }

response = requests.post(myToken, headers = headers)

jsonResponse = response.json()

print('jsonResponse: ' + str(jsonResponse))
```

Thanks

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Are you sure that you need to send `Grant_Type` with a capital `G` and a capital `T`?

Comment: I tried that way too but it didn't work.